# Solid region between two spheres in first octant.

Tags: calculus, volume

So I do not quite understand this question. I'm confused about the bounds of integration and I'd like an in-depth solution for this one, because I want to know how to select which boundaries to use.

The question is listed below:
[image]

Comment: Have you seen spherical coordinates?

Comment: Yes, I have. I think the bound would just be that theta and phi are both equal to pi/2, but the integration limits of the final part are a bit vague to me.

Comment: $\rho$ goes from $a$ to $b$ because we go from a distance of $a$ to the origin to a maximum distance of $b$ @AdamWarlock

Comment: Why would $\theta$ and $\phi$ be *equal* to $\pi/2$??? That would not cover the first octant at all: it is just a line.